# Strange shadows on render(cycles)

Tags: rendering

When I set sun or spot lamp on my scene,I don't know why I get those strange 'square' shadows on some areas of the mesh.I tried to increase the size and the angle of the lamp but they are still present on some more complex objects.I would like to get rid of these but don't want to change the direction of the lamp,what should I do?
[image]

Comment: maybe search for "terminator effect", yes increasing the size of the lamp should be one of the solutions

Comment: @moonboots :thank you for the advice,the effect is less visible but it is still present,the shadows are less present too,how to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure it can be fixed for the moment, I thought 2.8 would fix it but it looks like not... I guess you've already smoothed your object, which is the other solution... by the way we can barely see the artefacts on your screenshot  ;)